# Notifications style Google Calendar on Java EE

Tags: java, email, calendar, notifications, share

Good day!

I hope I can help out on this problem.

I have a list of emails in a table, and in another a Date and Time. Sending an Object to one or more emails, through a button, with the Share.
Any ideas for getting to a date dd / mm / yyyy anyone, I send a message to a list of emails automatically, ie without logging in, or interact with it?
Thanks for the help!

Note: Something similar to Google Calendar sends you a notification of some event days or hours before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of using JavaMail ?

You can do something like:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("from", "password");
                    }
                });
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(creds.getFrom()));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("to"));
message.setSubject("subject");
message.setText("Java EE 7 is cool!");
Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

The complete sample is available at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples/tree/master/javamail/definition

Comment: I could solve it using Quartz Scheduler. quartz-scheduler.org
Thanks for the replies.